# Prove uniquness of solution for a simple ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the equation $ x'=f\left(x\right) $ Where $ x(t) $ is a fucntion of $ t $.

Assume $ x_0 $ is a root of $ f(x) $. That is $ f(x_0)=0 $, and assume that is the only root in some neighborhood of $ x_0 $.

So $x(t)=x_0 $ is a trivial solution for the differential equation. Now, assume in addition that $ f $ is continuous and $ f \neq 0 $ in the neighborhood $ \left(x_{0}-\varepsilon,x_{0}\right) $. (Without loss of generality assume $f<0 in that neighborhood).

So we can write the differential equation (locally) as:

$ \frac{x'}{f\left(x\right)}=1 $

And thus $ \intop_{x}^{x_{0}}\frac{ds}{f\left(s\right)}=\left(t_{0}-t\right) $

(where $ x_{0}-\varepsilon<x<x_{0} $). Now, my question is:

How can I prove that if $ \intop_{x}^{x_{0}}\frac{ds}{f\left(s\right)}=\infty $ then the solution is unique (meaning, the locally solution for the differential equation in the neighborhood $(x_0-\varepsilon,x_0) $ does not cross the trivial solution $ x(t)=x_0 $ and thus can be extended.

and if $ \intop_{x}^{x_{0}}\frac{ds}{f\left(s\right)}<\infty $ then there is no uniquness for the solution for a given initial value.

Im sorry if I wrote things that does now make sense, Im starting a new course in differential equation and I do not feel comfortable yet with all the terms.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the solution were to cross, then the time that is computed with the integral has to be finite. So the integral being infinite prevents that.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thats also the explanation in my book. But I cannot understand whats the connection between the integral to the question " does the solutions cross". Can we prove it in a formal way?

Answer (score 1):

Assume that you have a solution $x(t)$ with $x(t_0)\ne x_0$ and $x(t_1)=x_0$, $t_1$ minimal with that property. Then by the separation process, as you wrote
$$
t_1-t_0=\int_{x(t_0)}^{x_0}\frac{ds}{f(s)}
$$
Now the left side is finite, the right side diverges by assumption, which gives a contradiction. So there can not be such a $t_1$.

Comment: How exactly our assumption imply that the right side diverge? I cannot see the connection between the integral and $ x(t) $. Also why would we assume that there exists such $ t_1 $? maybe $x(t)$ never gets the value $ x_0 $?

Comment: We start with assuming that the constant solution $x_0$ does not have the uniqueness property. This means a different solution will branch off or in at some point (or any point as it is autonomous). Now we take such a solution that takes values different from $x_0$ and at some point moves to $x_0$. This point by definition of the branching has finite time. So the left side is finite, and the right side is not. You wrote down the connection between integral and $x(t)$, otherwise please mark citations that you do not understand as such in the question.